# how to fill a pattern(rotated 25 degree)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, php-gd

Let's say i have a image [image]

i want to fill this with [image] with 25 degree.

i rotate the image in php GD which gave me [image]

then when i create a new pattern and apply. i got the [image]

below is the code

Html

```
<h1>sleeve long normal</h1>
 <canvas id="sleevelongnormal" width=436 height=567></canvas>
```

js

```
 function doD(var1,var2,var3) //var1=convas var2=img1 var3=img aka design
         {
            // alert(var3);
             t = document.getElementById(''+var1+'');
             ctxt = t.getContext('2d');


              var img1 = new Image();
              var img = new Image();
              img.onload = function () {

              img1.onload = function () {
                  //start();

                   ctxt.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

                ctxt.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

                var pattern = ctxt.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

                ctxt.rect(0, 0, sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
                ctxt.fillStyle = pattern;

                //var rotation = 90;
                //ctxt.rotate(rotation * Math.PI/180);
                ctxt.fill();

                ctxt.globalAlpha = .10;
                ctxt.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                ctxt.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                ctxt.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

                  }
              img1.src = var2;
          }
          img.src = var3;

             //alert(t);
         }
```

i want to achieve more or less like this 
[image]

Comment: The problem is that rotation introduces whitespace around the squares. Have you tried repeating the pattern first, then rotate?

Comment: @AndersLindahl thanks for the perfect direction! u saved my life